# iPhone app submission process

Tags: iphone

I heard that iPhone apps must also run on iPad without modifications, at iPhone resolution , and at 2X iPhone 3GS resolution to submit the app to App store. Is that information correction. Do I need to support for iPad(with 2X of iPhone)?

On What things app store mainly concentrate when we submit the application?

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Malleswar

Answer (score 1):

Unless you do something specific or weird to lock out the iPad paradigm or device, a normal iPhone app will run on the iPad in 1X and 2X zoom mode without modification.  You can check this with reasonable confidence using the SDK Simulator.

There is a long list in the [App Store Review Guidelines](http://developer.apple.com/appstore/guidelines.html) on Apple's iOS Developer Portal which lists many of the things that Apple reviews when you submit an app.  Read it carefully.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I checked my app already. Most of the UI is ok but UIalertview apperas very small on iPad simulator(in 2X). Does App store reject if my application does not look good on iPad even though I am targeting my application for iPhone and iPod touch?

Answer (score 0):

I personally find it exhaustive to read the App Store Guidelines.

I prefer to read the bottom line in places like:
[Common rejection reasons](http://iphoneincubator.com/blog/app-store/rejections)

It's like the difference between reading a manual and searching the web for answers